# How can we enable controlling different parameter of BackGroundSubtractorMOG module from Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently in need of a BackGroundSubtractor model for my project.  I found that the BackGroundSubtractorMOG in OpenCV source has more parameters that can be controlled than what its Python API allows.  Why is that?  Is it possible to provide control over all the parameters from Python itself?

Comment: Did you read http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html#backgroundsubtractormog?

Comment: Yes, I read the tutorial.  I have gone beyond the tutorial.  It does not answer my question still